# neo4j query performance takes a lot of time

Tags: json, neo4j

I am facing a query performance issue. Do let me know if I am making any mistake here.

I have created around 1700 (Router nodes) and around 4000 (interface nodes) where interfaces are connected to their respective routers using relation (has_interface).

Now I want to create a link between these interfaces. A link will be a relation. Every interface has an IfIPAddress prop associated with it. 
When I try to create a link using this query, it runs for a very long time, takes a lot of CPU  and then do not create any link.
Here is my query

```
MATCH (I:Interface), (I2:Interface)                              
FOREACH(p in FILTER(z in {props} WHERE z.OrigIPAddress = I.IfIPAddress and z.TermIPAddress = I2.IfIPAddress) |
MERGE (:Interface {IfIPAddress:p.OrigIPAddress})-[r:link]->(:Interface {IfIPAddress:p.TermIPAddress})
ON CREATE SET r = p
ON MATCH SET r = p)
```

Here is what I provide to neo4j using json and curl

```
{
   "params" : {
      "props" : [
         {
            "AreaId" : "",
            "OrigIPAddress" : "172.16.42.9",
            "OrigNodeID" : "192.168.1.221",
            "TermIPAddress" : "172.16.42.10",
            "TermNodeID" : "10.229.140.28",
            "eEntityStatus" : "1",
            "iTotalBW" : "0"
         }
      ]
   },
   "query" : "MATCH (I:Interface), (I2:Interface)                              FOREACH(p in FILTER(z in {props} WHERE z.OrigIPAddress = I.IfIPAddress and z.TermIPAddress = I2.IfIPAddress) |                              MERGE (:Interface {IfIPAddress:p.OrigIPAddress})-[r:link]->(:Interface {IfIPAddress:p.TermIPAddress})                              ON CREATE SET r = p                              ON MATCH SET r = p)"
}
```

This is what I am doing in the query
First in the FILTER I am removing all those links whose OrigIPAddress or TermIPAddress are not present in the neo4j
After that for every props, I am creating a link between the interfaces.

I am using neo4j 2.1. When neo4j server was running with default configurations it gave error as "OutOFMemory Exception"

I increased the heap size of the server and it is taking a lot of time

Let me know if anything I have missed.
Do let me know if you need logs.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: your query creates a cross product, i.e. it pulls in 8M pairs.

Try something like this first, and report back if it does not work.

```
FOREACH(p in {props} |
   MERGE (I:Interface{IfIPAddress:p.OrigIPAddress})
   MERGE (I2:Interface {IfIPAddress:p.TermIPAddress})
   MERGE (I)-[r:link]->(I2) 
   SET r = p
)
```

You should not set all the properties on `r` that's just a waste. Only set the properties there that you really need.

Instead of:

```
 SET r = p
```

do something like this:

```
 SET r.uptime = p.uptime
```

How many elements do you have in `{props}` ?

What is your current server configuration? In terms of heap, mmio etc?

Best to share `path/to/neo4j/data/graph.db/messages.log` for diagnostics.

Comment: In your query as per my understanding the first merge will create Interface (I) if the OrigIPAddress is not present which I do not want as the query purpose is to create Links and not interfaces.

I want to set all the props in r as I need them all but I dont think that will affect too much because its just setting.

Well I tried with only one element and its taking a hell lot of time. Though the count of props element goes to around 10000-20000

Comment: I tried your query and same result.
In the messages.log this is the only message which is repeating multiple time
2014-04-09 11:38:57.155+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 7971ms [total block time: 143.898s
These all I have changed\added
Max heap 4096 MB
org.neo4j.server.transaction.timeout=5000
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=90M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=3G
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=90M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=130M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=130M

Comment: Also Adding my web console stops working when I run these queries.
It shows error in red saying "Disconnected...please check your socket...something similar"

Comment: How to share the complete messages.log here ? Messages.log is pretty big file. Can you send me your id so that I can send you the file.

Comment: send it to michael at neotechnology.com how many elements are in your props array?

Comment: I am testing it with 1 element right now and still its not working. Though there are around 10000- 20000 elements in the props.

Comment: I got your logfile, you allocate too much memory for your machine, 3.5GB for MMIO + 4G heap you probably start to swap mid-way